# print web report in C#.Net

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I need to create a clients details report for a web based application in c#.Net. There will be multiple client details one by one.

When take print of this web page, the first page will be the cover page and the remaining pages contains clients details. The pages except the cover page should be numbered “page x of y” in the centre of the footer. The top of each page should display the client name that is the subject of the sub-report. If part of a sub-report section spans onto a new page, the whole section should be moved to the new page. Any solution for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would  create a template of my report with the ReportViewer control. Then I would push data into it from code behind or link it to my DB to generate report automatically. You can find a Getting start with report viewer [there](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReportViewerControl09062007051533AM/ReportViewerControl.aspx).